# Name is not defined in a list comprehension with multiple loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to unpack a complex dictionary and I'm getting a `NameError` in a list comprehension expression using multiple loops:

```
a={
  1: [{'n': 1}, {'n': 2}],
  2: [{'n': 3}, {'n': 4}],
  3: [{'n': 5}],
}
good = [1,2]
print [r['n'] for r in a[g] for g in good]
# NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have the order of your loops mixed up; they are considered nested from left to right, so `for r in a[g]` is the *outer* loop and executed first. Swap out the loops:

```
print [r['n'] for g in good for r in a[g]]
```

Now `g` is defined for the next loop, `for r in a[g]`, and the expression no longer raises an exception:

```
>>> a={
...   1: [{'n': 1}, {'n': 2}],
...   2: [{'n': 3}, {'n': 4}],
...   3: [{'n': 5}],
... }
>>> good = [1,2]
>>> [r['n'] for g in good for r in a[g]]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @IakovDavydov: It may help to think of the order of the `for` loops you'd use when doing a task with "traditional" `for` loops: the order of the `for` loops in a list comp is the same as the traditional order. OTOH, things are a little different with a nested list comp like `[[a+z for a in 'abc'] for z in 'xyz']` where the first `for` loop (reading left to right) is the inner loop, but that's because it's inside the inner list comp .