# Get all possible permutation of a list with list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've referenced this question [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/104420/8809592), where I faced a similar scenario that expressed in this question.

This time, I wanna generate all possible permutations(**without an empty list `[]`**)of a list , and store it in another single list. E.g. the target list is `a_list=[1, 2, 3]`, and I want something like:

```
[
[1], [2], [3], 
[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], 
[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]
]
```

---

I've tried this code, which worked successfully (using built-in `itertools` module):

```
import itertools    
perm = list()    
for i in range(1, len(a_list) + 1):
    perm.extend([list(x) for x in itertools.permutations(a_list, i)])
```

I wanna to try it in a list comprehension way, but I failed with this attempt:

```
perm = [list(x) for x in permutations(a_list, i) for i in range(1, len(a_list)+1)]
```

---

**So is there any feasible list comprehension method to do this stuff?**

Comment: You have the ordering of the loops the wrong way around... See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35479600/3001761, and please note that searching for the error message (which you should have included as part of a [mcve] in the question) would find you these answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments say, you have mixed up the order of the for loops. The first `for` is the outer loop, the second `for` is the inner loop (read left to right in a list comprehension).

This is the correct ordering:

```
import itertools   

a_list=[1, 2, 3]

perm = [list(x) for i in range(1, len(a_list)+1) for x in itertools.permutations(a_list, i)]
```

```
print(perm)

>>>[[1], [2], [3], 
    [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], 
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```